# Объединение объектов javascript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, объекты

Имеется массив объектов:

```
let arr = [
{
 id: 111,
 name: 'Ivan',
 salary: 5000,
 date: '2020-01-01' 
},
{
 id: 222,
 name: 'Oleg',
 salary: 3000,
 date: '2020-01-01' 
},
{
 id: 111,
 name: 'Ivan',
 salary: 5000,
 date: '2020-01-01' 
},
{
 id: 333,
 name: 'Anya',
 salary: 3000,
 date: '2020-01-02' 
},
{
 id: 444,
 name: 'Arman',
 salary: 5000,
 date: '2020-01-01' 
}]
```

Нужно группировать по определенным датам.
Не получается передать остальные значения кроме id и salary

```
let res = {};

arr.forEach(function(object){
    res[object.id] = (res[object.id] || 0) + object.salary;
});

let result = Object.keys(res).map(function(key){
    return { id : key, name: key, salary : res[key] }
});

console.dir(result);
```

В чем проблема? Как можно объединить не используя reduce

Comment: Что объединить? Напишите, какой результат Вы хотите получить.

Comment: Нужно вывести данные в виде : obj = { '2020-01-01' : { 111:{},222{}, 444{}, }, '2020-01-02' : { 333{} } }

Comment: И объекты с одиннаковым id прибавить между собой salary

Comment: а что за странное ограничение на reduce

Comment: Задача выполнить условие без reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи стандартного метода `Array.reduce()`

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: 'Oleg',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 333,
    name: 'Anya',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-02'
  },
  {
    id: 444,
    name: 'Arman',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  }
];

const res = arr.reduce(function(res, cur) {
  if (!res[cur.date]) {
    res[cur.date] = {};
  }
  if (!res[cur.date][cur.id]) {
    res[cur.date][cur.id] = {
      name: cur.name,
      salary: cur.salary
    };
  } else {
    res[cur.date][cur.id].salary += cur.salary;
  }
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Или без `reduce`

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: 'Oleg',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 333,
    name: 'Anya',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-02'
  },
  {
    id: 444,
    name: 'Arman',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  }
];

const res = {};
arr.forEach(function(cur) {
  if (!res[cur.date]) {
    res[cur.date] = {};
  }
  if (!res[cur.date][cur.id]) {
    res[cur.date][cur.id] = {
      name: cur.name,
      salary: cur.salary
    };
  } else {
    res[cur.date][cur.id].salary += cur.salary;
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ну и за что минусы?